# Embed word in power point using open xml c#

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml

i have a requirement to embed a word document in a powerpoint. i am using open xml (c#) for that. used "Docxtosource" to see how the embeding is done. below is the code which i got

```
private void GenerateEmbeddedObjectPart(ref EmbeddedObjectPart part)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        using (FileStream file = new FileStream(this.DocumentPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            file.CopyTo(ms);
       
        try
        {
            part.FeedData(ms);
        }
        finally
        {
            ms.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

The above code embeds the object but when tried to open it shows a prompt of how to open the document.
When i relooked the code generated by the DocxToSource code which is as below

```
private void GenerateEmbeddedObjectPart(ref EmbeddedObjectPart part)
        {
 string base64 ="base64string generated by the tool";
 Stream mem = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64), false);
            try
            {
                part.FeedData(mem);
            }
            finally
            {
                mem.Dispose();
            }
}
```

The base64 string generated by the DocxToSource tool has some headers embded when decoded. So how do we generate this headers and embed into the powerpoint. Or could you please redirect me to a documentation which has this embeding logic. Thanks a ton.

Comment: When I need to figure out how to do something with OpenXML, I create a document using the appropriate Office tools (in this case, Word & PowerPoint), save it, and then open it using Microsoft's _OpenXML Productivity Tool_ (no longer available on Microsoft.com, but findable on GitHub. By either directly opening a file and _Reflecting_ over it or by diffing two files, one with the feature I want and one without, I can usually figure things out

Comment: @Flydog57- Thats what i did. compared the string and code generated by DocxToSource(new open xml productivity tool). The tool is adding ole header. Not sure from where its getting. the ask is that.

Comment: The Productivity tool doesn't "add" anything, it just reads what's in the file

Comment: @Flydog57 - thank you for your response but it adds the program to run as header as well as footer. ultimately resorted to the interop. thank you once again.